# Virtual cursor app for android

Tags: android

I am using a flip phone that runs android without a touch screen, so I need an app the provides a cursor, just like the mouse of a PC, that can be controlled by the DPAD.

I need a FREE (as in "No payment") option for this, which ideally does not depend on Android's Accessibility service, support swipe (not only tap),  support screen edge scrolling.